# How do I know on-chain if a target address is a Safe?

Tags: safe-core

I know you can get the byte-code of an address, and then check against the stored byte-code of {GnosisSafeProxy.sol}  at specific version compiled with a specific compiler. If the comparison returns equal, then is true, that address is a Safe.

However, in this method, you cannot possible scale it to all multiple versions or compiled revisions of {GnosisSafeProxy.sol}. Therefore, does anybody know of a consistent way across to identify on-chain if a target address is a Safe?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `isSafe` method (or equivalent) you could call in the contracts to identify them on-chain, however you could scale the solution you mentioned to include at least the 5 main releases of the contracts, which should cover the vast majority of the cases. You can find them and the corresponding files [here](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/tree/main/src/assets).

Hope it helps,
Louis